# SFTP: Connection closed

Tags: ssh, sftp, openssh, sshd, synology

I'm trying to connect via sftp to my Synology NAS 215j running sftp server.
The sshd works great for root user, but when I do sftp as root, I'm getting `Connection closed` just after typing correct passphrase for my ssh key.

Here is the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config:**

```
Ciphers blowfish-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com

Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel ERROR
LoginGraceTime 60

MaxStartups 2
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 3

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile    %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
IgnoreRhosts yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PermitRootLogin without-password
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 600
ClientAliveCountMax 0
Banner /etc/ssh/issue.net
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
UseDNS no

ChrootDirectory none
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f DAEMON -u 000

Match User root
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Here is the verbose output:

```
$ sftp -P 22221 -vvv root@nas

OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to nas [192.168.1.51] port 22221.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4 pat OpenSSH_6.5*,OpenSSH_6.6* compat 0x14000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to nas:22221 as 'root'
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: original KEX proposal: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: Compat: skipping algorithm "curve25519-sha256@libssh.org"
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: compat KEX proposal: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug3: put_host_port: [nas]:22221
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/drewshg312/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [nas]:22221
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: blowfish-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1041/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:SkJiuE7k6Z2ooVXv2cb4PGTeXgh+xNjxMtDG+8Pfqw0
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.1.51]:22221
debug3: put_host_port: [nas]:22221
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/drewshg312/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [nas]:22221
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/drewshg312/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.1.51]:22221
debug1: Host '[nas]:22221' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug2: bits set: 1039/2048
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Connection refused
debug2: key: /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f97fc000610),
debug2: key: /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug3: input_userauth_banner
                             )        (       )     )
   (      *   )  *   )    ( /(   *   ))\ ) ( /(  ( /(
   )\   ` )  /(` )  /((   )\())` )  /(()/( )\()) )\())
((((_)(  ( )(_))( )(_))\ ((_)\  ( )(_))(_)|(_)\ ((_)\
 )\ _ )\(_(_())(_(_()|(_) _((_)(_(_()|_))   ((_) _((_)
 (_)_\(_)_   _||_   _| __| \| ||_   _|_ _| / _ \| \| |
  / _ \   | |    | | | _|| .` |  | |  | | | (_) | .` |
 /_/ \_\  |_|    |_| |___|_|\_|  |_| |___| \___/|_|\_|

UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS TO THIS SYSTEM IS FORBIDDEN AND WILL BE
PROSECUTED BY LAW!

DISCONNECT IMMIDIATELY IF YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED PERSON!

By accessing this system you agree that all your actions
will be monitored and logged.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:NWHiMGnH1Sz8K/cLRV9x493V6B6P8+oat6xtwFViZl4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:NWHiMGnH1Sz8K/cLRV9x493V6B6P8+oat6xtwFViZl4
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/drewshg312/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to nas ([192.168.1.51]:22221).
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 87380
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 4144, received 3136 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 24522.5, received 18557.5
debug1: Exit status 255
Connection closed
```

Please help! I'm pretty sure there is something in my sshd configuration, that I don't completely understand… I need someone to point my mistake

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Here is the log info, I'v got from `grep -i sftp /var/log/*`:

```
/var/log/synoinfo.conf.bad:sftpPort="22"
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec  5 12:54:25 nas-server entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[9165]: service_reload.c:33 synoservice: reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec  5 12:54:25 nas-server entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[9165]: service_reload.c:40 synoservice: [sftp] is not enabled, skip reload action
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec  5 12:54:25 nas-server entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[9165]: service_reload.c:53 synoservice: finish reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec  5 21:58:25 nas-server entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.Upgrade[1].start[22749]: service_pause_by_reason.c:27 synoservice: pause [sftp] by reason [smallupdate] ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec  5 21:58:25 nas-server entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.Upgrade[1].start[22749]: service_pause.c:39 synoservice: [sftp] pausing ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec  5 21:58:25 nas-server entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.Upgrade[1].start[22749]: service_pause.c:48 synoservice: [sftp] is already disable/pause.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec  5 21:58:25 nas-server entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.Upgrade[1].start[22749]: service_pause.c:89 synoservice: [sftp] paused.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 12 19:56:27 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[16689]: service_reload.c:33 synoservice: reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 12 19:56:27 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[16689]: service_reload.c:40 synoservice: [sftp] is not enabled, skip reload action
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 12 19:56:27 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[16689]: service_reload.c:53 synoservice: finish reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 14 14:09:02 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[27314]: service_reload.c:33 synoservice: reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 14 14:09:02 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[27314]: service_reload.c:40 synoservice: [sftp] is not enabled, skip reload action
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 14 14:09:02 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[27314]: service_reload.c:53 synoservice: finish reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 14 14:10:39 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[27623]: service_reload.c:33 synoservice: reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 14 14:10:39 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[27623]: service_reload.c:40 synoservice: [sftp] is not enabled, skip reload action
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 14 14:10:39 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[27623]: service_reload.c:53 synoservice: finish reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 15 18:00:53 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[13303]: service_reload.c:33 synoservice: reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 15 18:00:53 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[13303]: service_reload.c:40 synoservice: [sftp] is not enabled, skip reload action
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 15 18:00:53 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[13303]: service_reload.c:53 synoservice: finish reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 15 18:05:03 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[14018]: service_reload.c:33 synoservice: reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 15 18:05:03 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[14018]: service_reload.c:40 synoservice: [sftp] is not enabled, skip reload action
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 15 18:05:03 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.User.Home[1].set[14018]: service_reload.c:53 synoservice: finish reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 19:42:01 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.BandwidthControl.Protocol[1].set[12255]: service_reload.c:33 synoservice: reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 19:42:01 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.BandwidthControl.Protocol[1].set[12255]: service_reload.c:40 synoservice: [sftp] is not enabled, skip reload action
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 19:42:01 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.BandwidthControl.Protocol[1].set[12255]: service_reload.c:53 synoservice: finish reload [sftp].
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:29:43 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[17732]: service_start.c:108 synoservice: [sftp] starting ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:29:45 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[17732]: service_start.c:206 synoservice: [sftp] started.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:32:06 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[18453]: service_pause.c:39 synoservice: [sftp] pausing ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:32:08 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[18453]: service_pause.c:89 synoservice: [sftp] paused.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:32:10 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[18453]: service_start.c:108 synoservice: [sftp] starting ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:32:12 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[18453]: service_start.c:206 synoservice: [sftp] started.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:32:51 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[18960]: service_pause.c:39 synoservice: [sftp] pausing ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:32:52 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[18960]: service_pause.c:89 synoservice: [sftp] paused.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:32:55 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[18960]: service_start.c:108 synoservice: [sftp] starting ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:32:56 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[18960]: service_start.c:206 synoservice: [sftp] started.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:38:47 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[19744]: service_pause.c:39 synoservice: [sftp] pausing ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:38:48 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[19744]: service_pause.c:89 synoservice: [sftp] paused.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:38:50 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[19744]: service_start.c:108 synoservice: [sftp] starting ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:38:52 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[19744]: service_start.c:206 synoservice: [sftp] started.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:40:09 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[20292]: service_pause.c:39 synoservice: [sftp] pausing ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:40:11 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[20292]: service_pause.c:89 synoservice: [sftp] paused.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:40:13 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[20292]: service_start.c:108 synoservice: [sftp] starting ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 21:40:14 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[20292]: service_start.c:206 synoservice: [sftp] started.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 22:14:56 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[22807]: service_pause.c:39 synoservice: [sftp] pausing ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 22:14:58 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[22807]: service_pause.c:89 synoservice: [sftp] paused.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 22:14:58 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[22807]: service_stop.c:49 synoservice: [sftp] stopping ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 22:15:00 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[22807]: service_stop.c:106 synoservice: [sftp] stopped.
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 22:15:02 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[22990]: service_start.c:108 synoservice: [sftp] starting ...
/var/log/synoservice.log:Dec 17 22:15:03 nas entry.cgi_SYNO.Core.FileServ.FTP.SFTP[1].set[22990]: service_start.c:206 synoservice: [sftp] started.
```

Comment: You are connection to port `22221`, but there is not mark about using this port in your `sshd_config`. Connection seems to go to sshd server, but the logs about sftp are coming from somewhere else. Can you check the log directory for `sshd` failures?

Comment: @Jakuje, I'm running sshd on port 22222 and sftp server on port 22221. Should it be the same port?

Comment: @Jakuje, Port is set up in DSM GUI, so It can be omited in sshd_config - it works perfectly without defining it there... SFTP port is also set in DSM GUI... anyways I've tried different combinations. I've defined `port 22222` in `sshd_config` and set the same port for ssh and sftp in gui... Still the same result :(((

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but do you _need_ to SFTP as `root`? If not, you could just create a user with the privileges you need. (Make sure you go to the 'Applications' tab in the user's settings in DSM, and check FTP.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a problem on the server side. As soon as you request the SFTP subsystem you're receiving an end-of-file and it's exiting with a 255.

```
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
...  
debug1: Exit status 255
```

Can you check out the logs on the server? Probably grep in /var/log/

```
grep -i sftp /var/log/*
```

should return something helpful.

Comment: @jbahy, Thank you for reply! I'v updated my post, please check it out!

Comment: It looks like synology has disabled it on purpose. Here's a howto from their site on how to setup the sFTP server.

Comment: "Here's a howto..." where?

Comment: http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_setup_an_sftp-server